# VARRAY user defined element_type

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, varray

For VARRAY in Oracle syntax is: CREATE [OR REPLACE ] TYPE type_name AS | IS
VARRAY(max_elements) OF element_type [NOT NULL];

Can I create element_type as a record type in varray similar to nested table? If not why?
For example I will have 3 as varray size and store 3 address whose I also want to store sub address. Can I do by that in VARRAY?

Comment: You can create a varray of a user-defined object type - is that what you mean by a record type? Or as you've tagged this with PL/SQL do you mean a schema-level varray of a PL/SQL record type? It might be clearer if you include your existing type definitions for the non-varray types, how you're trying to create the varray, and what error or issue you have doing that?

Comment: Sample data would be helpful to answer.